# Generate a lattice using python

Tags: python, python-itertools

How to generate something like

```
[(), (1,), (1,2), (1,2,3)..., (1,2,3,...n)]
```

and

```
[(), (4,), (4,5), (4,5,6)..., (4,5,6,...m)]
```

then take the product of them and merge into

```
[(), (1,), (1,4), (1,4,5), (1,4,5,6), (1,2), (1,2,4)....(1,2,3,...n,4,5,6,...m)]
```

?

For the first two lists I've tried the powerset recipe in https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes , but there will be something I don't want, like `(1,3), (2,3)`

For the product I've tested with `chain` and `product`, but I just can't merge the combinations of tuples into one.

Any idea how to do this nice and clean? Thanks!

Comment: Just nit-picking, a single element tuple is written as `(4,)`. Also if you want to merge you might want to use `set` elements instead of tuples.

Comment: Are these lists meant to be unending?

Comment: You might want to decompose your problem.

For instance :
- create one function generating a tuple beginning at x, with length n (should not be too difficult with range)
- create one function generating a list of length m of tuples beginning at x (should not be difficult with the first function)
- create one function merging 2 tuples (should not be difficult with  set)
- create one function merging a tuple with a list of tuples (should not be difficult with the previous function°

Comment: @filmor Sorry, I forgot to add the comma at the end of the tuples!

Comment: @ScottHunter Just to express that the end of the lists should be specified via something like a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that, single element tuples are denoted like this `(1,)`.

```
a = [(), (1,), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
b = [(), (4,), (4, 5), (4, 5, 6)]

from itertools import product
for item1, item2 in product(a, b):
    print item1 + item2
```

**Output**

```
()
(4,)
(4, 5)
(4, 5, 6)
(1,)
(1, 4)
(1, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 5, 6)
(1, 2)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 2, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 4, 5, 6)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

If you want them in a list, you can use list comprehension like this

```
from itertools import product
print [sum(items, ()) for items in product(a, b)]
```

Or even simpler,

```
print [items[0] + items[1] for items in product(a, b)]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the commas!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any special imports:

```
start = 1; limit = 10
[ range(start, start + x) for x in range(limit) ]
```

With `start = 1` the output is:
`[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]`

If you want to take the product, maybe using `itertools` might be most elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
>>> a=[(), (1,), (1,2), (1,2,3)]
>>> b=[(), (4,), (4,5), (4,5,6)]
>>> for ix in a:
...   for iy in b:
...      print ix + iy
... 
()
(4,)
(4, 5)
(4, 5, 6)
(1,)
(1, 4)
(1, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 5, 6)
(1, 2)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 2, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 4, 5, 6)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```